# How to calculate the mean of each cluster after clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Here I have clustered a data and get the array about the label:

```
player_playoffs_career_data_label = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=50).fit_predict(player_playoffs_career_data)
print(player_playoffs_career_data_label)
```

```
[24 31  7 ... 30 30 30]
```

And then how can I calculate the mean of each cluster (perhaps just calculate the mean of the center point of each cluster). I mean how to select the center point of each cluster and calculate its mean.

After that how can I get the number about the row-numbers of the points which appear in the cluster with the highest mean.

About the raw data(player_playoffs_career_data):

```
[[  17  106   38 ...    4    2    0] 
 [ 237 8851 5762 ... 1419 1050    4] 
 [  15  415  195 ...   45   43   49] 
 ...
 [   3    9    2 ...    1    0    0] 
 [  15   67   26 ...    7    2    0] 
 [   1    1    0 ...    0    0    0]]
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: can you explain what is your expected output ?

Comment: find out the cluster with the highest mean and return the items in this cluster (by printing the index of row for these items)

Comment: Or maybe who can help me create new datasets from these clusters. Change these clusters into several specific matrixes. And then I can calculate the mean of the matrixes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `K-means` , you should follow these steps -

1. Select K random points (You can check [Elbow Method](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html) to find a good K value)
2. After selecting these K random points, you can calculate the euclidian distance of each data point from these K cluster centers
3. Assign data point to the cluster which is at a minimum distance from it.
4. Now you can distinctly tell your `K clusters`, calculate the mean of within-cluster elements, that will be your `new cluster center`.
5. Repeat these above until the membership of cluster elements don't change significantly.

Comment: Well, if I can't use `k-means`, just use `AgglomerativeClustering`. How can I calculate the mean of these clusters. What I need is about which one is the best cluster and who are in this cluster.